Бот vkbottle стал выдавать ошибку
Помогите пожалуйста новичку с проблемой
Простенький бот магазина ВК через vkbottle реагировал на новый заказ сообщением и работал исправно долгое время,
вдруг внезапно стал выдавать такую ошибку:
pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for MarketOrderNew
object -> preview_order_items -> 0 -> item -> category
    none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
object -> preview_order_items -> 1 -> item -> category
    none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
object -> preview_order_items -> 2 -> item -> category
    none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
object -> preview_order_items -> 3 -> item -> category
    none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)

Вот код бота:
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
from vkbottle import GroupEventType, GroupTypes, VKAPIError
from config import token
import asyncio
    
    
bot = Bot(token=token)
    
@bot.on.raw_event(GroupEventType.MARKET_ORDER_NEW, dataclass=GroupTypes.MarketOrderNew)
async def new_order_handler(event: GroupTypes.MarketOrderNew):
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
    try:
        await bot.api.messages.send(
            peer_id=event.object.user_id,
            message="Спасибо за заказ! Продавец свяжется с вами в ближайшее время!",
            random_id=0
        )
    except VKAPIError(901):
        pass
    
bot.run_forever()

